# My Android app is installing and but not launching on device?

Tags: android-studio

I am using a source code which i previously works one year before ,which is error free.Now i open and causing it installed but not launching..
What will be the reasons for this runtime error?
How to find the runtime errors in Android Studio?
Please help me,

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Its just crashing,even splash activity is not showing....

Comment: Try to read your Logcat. And Please Also post a screenshot of it here.

Comment: did logcat show anything?

Comment: Try to read your Logcat. And Please Also post a screenshot of it here.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhKhS.png

Comment: my logcat screenshot is attached , pleasde give a loog